# How to use QSignalMapper with QActions created dynamically?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, signals-slots, qsignalmapper

I'd like to create a dynamic menu which enumerates all `QDockWidget` from my `QMainWindow` and allows to show/hide the `QDockWidgets`, so far I got this code:

```
class PluginActionsViewDocks():

    def __init__(self, main_window):
        self.main_window = main_window

        mapper = QSignalMapper(self.main_window)

        self.actions = []
        for dock in main_window.findChildren(QtWidgets.QDockWidget):
            action = create_action(
                main_window, dock.windowTitle(),
                slot=mapper.map,
                tooltip='Show {0} dock'.format(dock.windowTitle())
            )
            mapper.setMapping(action, dock)
            self.actions.append(action)

        mapper.mapped.connect(self.toggle_dock_widget)
        help_menu = main_window.menuBar().addMenu('&View')
        setattr(help_menu, "no_toolbar_policy", True)
        add_actions(help_menu, tuple(self.actions))

    def toggle_dock_widget(self, dock_widget):
        print("toggle_dock_widget")
```

The menu is populated with all QDockWidget windowTitles but when i press each of them the slot `toggle_dock_widget` is not called. `create_action` is a helper which creates the QAction and connect the triggered signal to `slot`.

The thing is, I don't really understand quite well how QSignalMapper works but my intuition tells me it's the right choice for this particular problem.

What could I be missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's aleady a built-in dock-widget menu. Just right-click any dock title-bar, or any tool-bar or menu-bar. See: [QMainWindow::createPopupMenu](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#createPopupMenu).

PS:

The reason why your `QSignalMapper` code doesn't work is probably because you are connecting to the wrong overload of the `mapped` signal. Try this instead:

```
    mapper.mapped[QtWidgets.QWidget].connect(self.toggle_dock_widget)
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks to point it out. After asking my question i had discovered that builtin one. Still, i'm pretty much interested on figuring out what's wrong with my snippet so next time ill know much better how to use properly qsignalmapper. Any idea? +1